# Toggle the display of the mode-line

Tags: mode-line

The intention of the following code is to toggle the display of the mode-line when called repeatedly.  Although the mode-line is removed when first called, the mode-line does not show up again.  I want the function to toggle the mode-line properly.

```
(defvar-local ramona-mode-line-rflog nil
  "Toggle switch for mode-line display.")

(defun ramona-mode-line ()
  "TODO."
  (interactive)

  (setq-local mode-line-format
               (if ramona-mode-line-rflog
                   (progn
                     (setq mode-line-format ramona-mode-line-rflog)
                     (setq ramona-mode-line-rflog nil))
                 (setq ramona-mode-line-rflog mode-line-format)
                 (setq mode-line-format nil)))

  (force-mode-line-update t))
```

Comment: You are setting `mode-line-format` inside the `if` and then you are setting it **again** to the result of the `if`. Lose the outer `setq-local`: just keep the `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented:

> You are setting mode-line-format inside the if and then you are setting it again to the result of the if. Lose the outer setq-local: just keep the if.

Just in case my comment is not clear, here's what I mean:

```el
(defun ramona-mode-line ()
  "TODO."
  (interactive)

  (if ramona-mode-line-rflog
      (setq mode-line-format ramona-mode-line-rflog
            ramona-mode-line-rflog nil)
    (setq ramona-mode-line-rflog mode-line-format
          mode-line-format nil))
  (force-mode-line-update t))
```

And BTW, you can set multiple variables with one `setq`: you don't need `progn` here. Do `C-h f setq` for the details.